# Chain loading grub2 via PXELINUX for UEFI CentOS 8 installation

Tags: linux, centos, pxe-boot, uefi

We support multiple linux distributions and we install them via the UEFI version of pxelinux. Before CentOS 8 you could just directly load the kernel and the initrd via the UEFI version of PXElinux. Starting with CentOS 8 for some reason you now have to load the installer via GRUB 2.

Has anyone figured out how to chainload grub2 from PXELINUX in UEFI mode or alternatively how to load the CentOS 8 installer over the network via ipxe on a system in UEFI mode? Since we have 40 different installer options via UEFI we can't completely change how we handle our network installs just because CentOS 8 decided to change how they do everything.

Comment: Have you read the [docs](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/performing_an_advanced_rhel_installation/preparing-for-a-network-install_installing-rhel-as-an-experienced-user#configuring-a-tftp-server-for-uefi-based-clients_preparing-for-a-network-install)?